# OR in custom conditional formatting formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets I have a table like this:

```
+-------+-------+------+------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |  C   |  D   |   B   |
+-------+-------+------+------+-------+
| color | color | none | none | color |
+-------+-------+------+------+-------+
```

and I would like to color the background of cells that contain `A` or `B`.

Is there any custom formula that could help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the relevant row is the first, please select it and try Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
 =or(A1="A",A1="B")
```

Choose your Formatting style and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: it works great but remeber to use ";" instead ","   '=or(A1="A";A1="B") '  it works for ranges too:) thanks for help

Comment: Thanks for that comment too:) to change locale i have to change spreadsheets properties?